# A question regarding two random variables and independence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, elementary-set-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Consider two random variables $X$ and $Y$. Allegedly, $P(X\in A,Y\in B)= P(X\in A)P(Y\in B)$ if and only if $\forall a,b$, $P(X\leq a, Y\leq b)= P(X\leq a)P(Y\leq b)$. First of all, is this correct? If so, how should one go about proving it?

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ quantified universally?  If the original statement is true for all subsets $A$ and $B$, then the forward direction is easy.  The proof in the other direction may require the language of Borel sigma algebras.

Comment: I have no idea what "quantified universally" means. The author of my book was not particularly specific. It's a book in elementary probability theory so and I don't think it is expected from the reader to know about things such as Borel sigma algebras, whatever that is. Perhaps that is why the proof was omitted. The author claimed that it could be proven with basic axioms of probability though.

Comment: Being less precise, you need to know what $A$ and $B$ are.  Are $A$ and $B$ fixed, particular sets?  Are $A$ and $B$ arbitrary sets?  Are they sets of a certain type?  The axioms of measure theory are essentially the same as the axioms of probability, but one has to make clear in what family $A$ and $B$ live before one can explain the correspondence.  The typical best (most general possibility) that one could hope for is when $A$ and $B$ are what are called Borel sets.

Comment: I assume they're just arbitrary subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: As @JoeBlitzstein mentions in the answers, using arbitrary subsets (and assuming the axiom of choice) is actually impossible.  One reason that the proof may be omitted is that the precise, correct statement is quite technical to even state.

Comment: I suppose I'll have to revisit it when I am more educated, thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is geared towards the OP, who has not had measure theory.  So, the OP can see some of the ideas behind the computation.

Sketch: The forward direction is straight-forward if we allow $A=(-\infty,a]$ and $B=(-\infty,b]$, then $\operatorname{Pr}(X\in A)=\operatorname{Pr}(X\leq a)$.  In this case, the statements become identical, so the second statement is a special case of the first one.

For the backwards direction, suppose first that $A=[a_1,a_2]$ and $B=[b_1,b_2]$.  Then,
$$
\operatorname{Pr}(X\in A,Y\in B)=\operatorname{Pr}(X\leq a_2,X\geq a_1, Y\leq b_2,Y\geq b_1).
$$
Now, we can start rewriting this in terms of the inequalities of the form $X\leq a$ and $Y\leq b$.  In particular, the event $X\leq a_2$ is the same as the union of the disjoint events $X\in A$ or $X\leq a_1$.  Therefore, 
$$
\operatorname{Pr}(X\in A,Y\in B)=\operatorname{Pr}(X\leq a_2,Y\in B)-\operatorname{Pr}(X\leq a_1,Y\in B).
$$
Applying the same reasoning to $Y\in B$, we get
\begin{align*}
&=\left(\operatorname{Pr}(X\leq a_2,Y\leq b_2)-\operatorname{Pr}(X\leq a_2,Y\leq b_1)\right)-\left(\operatorname{Pr}(X\leq a_1,Y\leq b_2)-\operatorname{Pr}(X\leq a_1,Y\leq b_1)\right)\\
&=\operatorname{Pr}(X\leq a_2,Y\leq b_2)-\operatorname{Pr}(X\leq a_2,Y\leq b_1)-\operatorname{Pr}(X\leq a_1,Y\leq b_2)+\operatorname{Pr}(X\leq a_1,Y\leq b_1).
\end{align*}
Using the assumed second part of the if and only if, we get the following
$$
=\operatorname{Pr}(X\leq a_2)\operatorname{Pr}(Y\leq b_2)-\operatorname{Pr}(X\leq a_2)\operatorname{Pr}(Y\leq b_1)-\operatorname{Pr}(X\leq a_1)\operatorname{Pr}(Y\leq b_2)+\operatorname{Pr}(X\leq a_1)\operatorname{Pr}(Y\leq b_1).
$$
Factoring this expression according to $X$ probabilities gives
$$
=\operatorname{Pr}(X\leq a_1)(\operatorname{Pr}(Y\leq b_1)-\operatorname{Pr}(Y\leq b_2))+\operatorname{Pr}(X\leq a_2)(\operatorname{Pr}(Y\leq b_2)-\operatorname{Pr}(Y\leq b_1)).
$$
Now, factoring out the common factor of $\operatorname{Pr}(Y\leq b_2)-\operatorname{Pr}(Y\leq b_1)$ gives
$$
=(\operatorname{Pr}(X\leq a_2)-\operatorname{Pr}(X\leq a_1))(\operatorname{Pr}(Y\leq b_2)-\operatorname{Pr}(Y\leq b_1))=\operatorname{Pr}(X\in A)\operatorname{Pr}(Y\in B).
$$
Using the same approach, you can extend this to the case where $A$ and $B$ are (countable) unions of intervals (and beyond).  The notation, however, gets more and more complicated (and quite annoying).  That's why we need more advanced tools to describe this properly.

Answer (score 3):

This is correct if $A$ and $B$ are assumed to be Borel sets in $\mathbb{R}$ (but not true in general if they are allowed to be completely arbitrary subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ – in that case the quantities in the first equation may even be undefined!). The forward direction follows from taking $A = (-\infty, a]$ and $B = (-\infty, b]$. The reverse direction requires measure theory to prove; the neatest way I know is to use one of my favorite theorems from measure theory, the pi-lambda theorem (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system ).